# Has there ever been a formal definition of "predicative"?

Tags: logic, definition

In mathematical logic, there is a notion of "predicative definitions". I understand what a predicative definition is, intuitively, but I am interested in a formalization of that notion. Has any mathematician ever formalized and made rigorous a definition of predicative? I would love to see such a definition.

Comment: In fact, there's even now quite a lively debate around the subject, even in a very coarse sense (namely whether the ordinal $\Gamma_0$ is predicatively justifiable); see e.g. [Avron's recent article *Poincare-Weyl's predicativity*](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~aa/Gamma_0.pdf).

Comment: The real question is, of course, whether there is a *predicative* definition of predicative definition. (Not just because it's funny, but also because it would mean the notion is strong enough to describe itself.)

Comment: Incidentally, the accepted answer is AI-generated garbage - Gentzen never worked on predicative arithmetic.